# Details on OV7670

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, sensors, sketch, robotics

I am thinking of working on a project based on a camera module OV7670. I am making a security system using an arduino where detected motion (I am also using a PIR sensor) will trigger the camera module. I wanted to get all kinds of information needed to work with the camera module in this kind of project.

I am not expecting a very long answer rearding everything about the module. The most important points and maybe a few references would be enough. It would also be helpful if programming reference for the camera module is also provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This post](http://www.arducam.com/camera-modules/0-3mp-ov7670/) is a link to a blog that describes the pinout and connections, along with some general information. They also have a link to [an "ArduCAM" library](https://github.com/ArduCAM/Arduino/tree/master/ArduCAM) with [an example](https://github.com/ArduCAM/Arduino/blob/master/ArduCAM/examples/REVC/ArduCAM_OV7670_Camera_Playback/ArduCAM_OV7670_Camera_Playback.ino) utilizing your camera model.